# 'Already up-to-date' Git Message Incorrect

Tags: git, merge

Say that I have one master branch `[M]`, and many feature branches off of this master branch `[F1, S1]`. I want the master branch to be fully tested, so I make a branch off of master `[J]` to merge *all* feature branches into and test them first before merging back into master. This works! I merge `[F1]` and `[S1]` into `[J]`, and then `[J]` into `[M]`, all good to go.

Now a period has passed and I want to do this again, so I create a new branch off of `[M]`, call it `[K]`, and do the same thing with my new feature branches. `[S1]` has been updated, so I go ahead and merge `[S1]` into `[K]` and all is good.

Now is where it starts to get a little bit confusing, but the details of this next part don't matter too much. One of these features, say `[F1]` needs to be built off of the `[J]` branch, so I merge `[F1]` into `[J]`. I still want the `[F1]` features in `[K]`, so I then go ahead and merge `[J]` into `[K]`.

A few things to keep in mind here, `[S1]` was previously merged into `[J]`. Now `[S1]` has been updated and merged into `[K]` which works fine, and then the merging of `[J]` into `[K]` happens.

Now, when I go to make another update to `[S1]` and try to merge it into `[K]`, it says that `[S1]` is "already up-to-date" when I have clearly just made changes to it. Looking back at the merge history, merging `[J]` into `[K]` is what caused this problem as it got rid of some `[S1]` changes, but I am not sure why.

What is causing this problem, and what can I do in the future to avoid it?

Here is a quick illustration of the process:

```
[M]____       ____       ____[M]
       \     /    \     /
       |\   /     |\   /|
       | [J]      | [K] \
       |          |   \  \
    [F1, S1]     [S1]  |  \
                      [J] [S1]*
```

where `[S1]*` is the branch that has updates to `[S1]` that I tried to merge in, but it says "already up-to-date".

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your story exactly. I mostly get it, but not the critical part. Would you be able to post simulated commands with trivial commits we could cut and paste to reproduce your situation? Obviously, the exact state of `[S1]` and `[J]` at that final problematic merge is critical, and that's where I'm a little fuzzy...

Comment: Are you sure the `[S1]` commit was made _after_ merging `[J]` to `[K]`?

Comment: When Git says it's up to date, it really is. To see *why*, try `git log --all --graph --decorate` (which is usually too much so try `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline` and/or add `--simplify-by-decoration` to that as well).